# I can't seed my database in a one to one relationship

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to seed my database but I am having an issue. I am making use of the one to one/null relationship in Entity Framework.
Below is my entity objects and the relationship.

```
 public class ApplicationSetting
 {
    //This is the primary key of this table entity
    public int ApplicationSettingID { get; set; }

    public string SmtpServer { get; set; }

    public string AlternateCompanyEmail { get; set; }

    public int SmtpPort { get; set; }

    public string SmtpUsername { get; set; }
}


public class LivechatSetting
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] //This is giong to enable an auto increment on the field
    public int? ApplicationSettingID { get; set; }

    public string LivechatEmail { get; set; }

    public int OperatorsMaximumchat { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan ResumptionTime { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan ClosingTime { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan ChatTimeOut { get; set; }
}
```

The relationship in my DatabaseContext class

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationSetting>()
            .HasOptional(client => client.LivechatSetting)
            .WithRequired(client => client.ApplicationSetting);
```

I am able to successfully save data into `ApplicationSetting` entity table in my db.

But when I try to use the id of the `ApplicationSetting` table to seed value into my `LivechatSetting` table I get the error below.

> A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a
>   store-generated column. Column: 'ApplicationSettingID'. Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A dependent
>   property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated
>   column. Column: 'ApplicationSettingID'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 26:                 context.LivechatSettings.Add(setting); Line
>   27:  Line 28:                 result = context.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved it myself. Follow that link for solution. weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/…. I followed their example

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, if "ApplicationSettingID" field is primary key of "ApplicationSetting' table

and if "Livechatsetting" is referenced table with "ApplicationSettingID" as foreign key.

Making "ApplicationSettingID" of "Livechatsetting" as identity(auto genereated field) will naturally give error

Comment: yeah I believe you right. cos I have been look at that value.

Comment: But I tried something like  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] . It still gave error. Please how do I set it to a foriegn key with out an auto generated value. Could you help me with code.

Comment: @user2754532 I think [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] attribute should be set for ApplicationSettingID field of ApplicationSetting table, check if that helps

Comment: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table LivechatSetting when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: Is the table "LivechatSetting" created in the database? check its design, if "ApplicationSettingID" is showing as identity column or not

Comment: It is. I am trying to read from Microsoft key relationship system. Mayb that would help

Comment: Just presently trying to restructure the relationship between the two tables.

Comment: Finally I solved it myself. Tahnks alot sankoobaba. http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx. I followed their example